# Writing "recall_score()" breaks org-mode export

Tags: org-mode, org-export

After writing the expression `recall_score()` in one of my org-mode files I was no longer able to export into html (or other formats), and I got the following error

```
Reference ‘score’ not found in this buffer
```

Is there a reason for this to happen?

My Emacs version is

```
GNU Emacs 25.2.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.21) of 2017-09-22, modified by Debian
```

and my org-mode version is

```
Org-mode version 8.2.10 (release_8.2.10 @ /usr/share/emacs/25.2/lisp/org/)
```

Comment: This has been fixed many moons ago. Your version of org-mode is ancient: please upgrade.

Comment: I stand corrected: the behavior is as you describe even in the latest version. See [this thread](http://lists.gnu.org/r/emacs-orgmode/2018-01/msg00489.html) from the mailing list. The suggested workaround is to add a zero-width space before the underscore if you don't want it to be interpreted as an inline source block evaluation. But you should still upgrade :-)

Comment: Thank you for the insight @NickD! I agree, I'll catch up with the times. Btw, just for my future reference, how did you come across the result from the mailing list? Did you google it, or search a different website?

Comment: I have a local clone of the org-mode git repo.  I did  `git log --grep=inline-src` to find relevant commits and found one that looked promising. The ML list reference was in the [commit message](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/248bc9631b17c6b56a44dc0aedc50bc31607e27f)  (Nicolas Goaziou, the org mode maintainer, is very good about adding such references to his commit messages and, as we have seen here, they can be very useful).

Comment: That's neat! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I was writing an inline commmand to call a code block or function, since the expression I wrote includes something of the form `call_<name>()`.

It's explained in [this documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-code-blocks.html).